# How do you enable/configure a site collection app catalog in SP 2016 on-premises?

Tags: 2016, spfx, site-collection, app-catalog

After extensive searching, I can't seem to be able to find any information online regarding how to set up a site collection app catalog on SP 2016 on-premises. All the guides are for SP Online / O365.

We have SP 2016 Feature Pack 2, which supports SPFx webparts, and I have a webpart ready to deploy, and I want to use the site collection app catalog rather than a farm-wide app catalog site, if possible.

Is it possible to set up a site collection app catalog in SP 2016?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Site Collection app catalogs are only supported in SharePoint Online. Instead, you have to use the centralized farm-wide app catalog.

Comment: the app catalog is also associated with each Web Application which means you can have a app catalog for each web application.