# App Catalog site for SPFx Webparts only - do we have to set up the shadow app domain?

Tags: 2016, spfx, dns, app-catalog

As a follow up question to [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/273213/8992):

So given that we can't use site collection App Catalogs in SP 2016 on-premises, and we must use a centralized farm-wide App Catalog site, a lot of the instructions for setting that up involve configuring DNS to have a shadow app domain, because in the old app model, the "apps" were actually sites unto themselves, but they ran in a different domain than the main "regular" SharePoint sites.

However, we are not going to be developing any "apps" in the old app model, we are *only* going to be developing SPFx webparts, and we only need the App Catalog as a mechanism for deploying those webparts.

Given that (presumably) the webparts will be running on SharePoint pages in "regular" SharePoint sites that are in the main "regular" SharePoint domain, do we need to configure DNS to set up the shadow domain at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not documented, no you shouldn't need to.